# Auto Scroll down and filters in php using javascript and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've a issue with integrating auto scroll down and filters in php which have the supporting languages javascript and ajax..

```
    <script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#container2').scrollPagination({

        nop     : 12, // The number of posts per scroll to be loaded
        offset  : 0, // Initial offset, begins at 0 in this case
        error   : '', // When the user reaches the end this is the message that is
                                    // displayed. You can change this if you want.
        delay   : 100, // When you scroll down the posts will load after a delayed amount of time.
                       // This is mainly for usability concerns. You can alter this as you see fit
        scroll  : true // The main bit, if set to false posts will not load as the user scrolls. 
                       // but will still load if the user clicks.

    });

});

</script>
```

the above javascript is included in file. with the following ajax arguments to the php file which takes category or category + sub category or default else part.

```
   (function($) {

    $.fn.scrollPagination = function(options) {

        var settings = {
            nop     : 10, // The number of posts per scroll to be loaded
            offset  : 0, // Initial offset, begins at 0 in this case
            error   : '', // When the user reaches the end this is the message that is
                                        // displayed. You can change this if you want.
            delay   : 500, // When you scroll down the posts will load after a delayed amount of time.
                           // This is mainly for usability concerns. You can alter this as you see fit
            scroll  : true // The main bit, if set to false posts will not load as the user scrolls. 
                           // but will still load if the user clicks.
        }

        // Extend the options so they work with the plugin
        if(options) {
            $.extend(settings, options);
        }

        // For each so that we keep chainability.
        return this.each(function() {       

            // Some variables 
            $this = $(this);
            $settings = settings;
            var offset = $settings.offset;
            var busy = false; // Checks if the scroll action is happening 
                              // so we don't run it multiple times

            // Custom messages based on settings
            if($settings.scroll == true) $initmessage = '';
            else $initmessage = '';

            // Append custom messages and extra UI
            $this.append('<div class="content"></div><div class="loading-bar">'+$initmessage+'</div>');

            function getData() {

                // Post data to ajax.php
                $.post('ajax.php', {
                    category :$('#category').val(),
                    category1:$('#category1').val(),
                    subcat:$('#subcat').val(),
                    area:$('#filter_area1').val(),
                    action        : 'scrollpagination',
                    number        : $settings.nop,
                    offset        : offset,

                }, function(data) {

                    // Change loading bar content (it may have been altered)
                    $this.find('.loading-bar').html($initmessage);

                    // If there is no data returned, there are no more posts to be shown. Show error
                    if(data == "") { 
                        $this.find('.loading-bar').html($settings.error);   
                    }
                    else {

                        // Offset increases
                        offset = offset+$settings.nop; 

                        // Append the data to the content div
                        $this.find('.content').append(data);

                        // No longer busy!  
                        busy = false;

                    }   

                });

            }   
                             getData(); // Run function initially


            // If scrolling is enabled
            if($settings.scroll == true) {
                // .. and the user is scrolling
                $(window).scroll(function() {

                    // Check the user is at the bottom of the element
                    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $this.height() && !busy) {

                        // Now we are working, so busy is true
                        busy = true;

                        // Tell the user we're loading posts
                        $this.find('.loading-bar').html('');

                        // Run the function to fetch the data inside a delay
                        // This is useful if you have content in a footer you
                        // want the user to see.
                        setTimeout(function() {

                            getData();

                        }, $settings.delay);

                    }   
                });
            }

            // Also content can be loaded by clicking the loading bar/
            $this.find('.loading-bar').click(function() {

                if(busy == false) {
                    busy = true;
                    getData();
                }

            });

        });
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Based on scroll down action it appends the data at the end. now i want to integrate this with filetering concept. I've one dropdown box, based on onchange function the data should change. Can anyone tell me how to pass arguments through ajax and change data based on filtering?? Am new to javascript and ajax..